# Efficiently write a SQL query that needs to loop / join an unknown number of times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a table structure like this:

```
Order Table
OrderId int
OrderValue decimal

Payment Table
PaymentId int
OrderId int
PaymentAmount decimal
PaymentDate datetime
```

An order can have many payments. I need to find which is the first payment, ordered by date, which when added to the previous ones, is greater than or equal to the order value.

So if I have the following:

```
| OrderId | OrderValue |
|       1 |       1000 |

| PaymentId | OrderId | PaymentAmount | PaymentDate |
|         1 |       1 |           100 | 2014-02-01  |
|         2 |       1 |           500 | 2014-02-02  |
|         3 |       1 |           400 | 2014-02-03  |
|         4 |       1 |           100 | 2014-02-04  |
```

OrderId 1 is paid off when PaymentId 3 is created (OrderValue 1000 = 100+500+400).

I can do think of 3 ways of doing this; using a cursor, self joining the payments table many times or just loading the data up an application and going over it the old fashioned way via code. Can anyone think of how I could avoid these solutions or even why I should go with one of the solutions I've thought of?

This will ultimately end up in a SSRS report (using SQL Server 2008)

Comment: Which DBMS (and which version) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Looks like this should be doable using a window function (and a running sum)

Comment: Just updated question with the SQL Server tag. 2008

Comment: If you google "SQL Running Total" you will find examples.   You can also do running totals in SSRS, so you might want to look into handling it that way.

Comment: Looks promising, thanks @TabAlleman

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will work

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Payment p JOIN Order o ON o.OrderId = p.OrderId
WHERE   (   SELECT SUM(p2.PaymentAmount)
            FROM Payment p2 ON p2.OrderId = o.OrderId 
            WHERE p2.PaymentDate <= p.PaymentDate 

        ) >= o.OrderValue 
AND p.PaymentDate = (   SELECT MIN(p3.PaymentDate)
                        FROM Payment p3 ON p.OrderId = o.OrderId 
                        WHERE ( SELECT SUM(p4.PaymentAmount)
                                FROM Payment p4 ON p4.OrderId = o.OrderId 
                                WHERE p4.PaymentDate <= p3.PaymentDate 
                           ) >= o.OrderValue
                   )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're partial to CTE's to avoid having to duplicate the SUM logic, this works for me:

```
WITH paidInFullPayments(PaymentId, OrderId, PaymentDate)
AS
(SELECT p.PaymentId, p.OrderId, p.PaymentDate
    FROM payment p
    INNER JOIN OrderTable o ON p.OrderId = o.OrderId
    WHERE (SELECT sum(p2.PaymentAmt) 
                FROM payment p2 
                WHERE p2.PaymentDate <= p.PaymentDate
                    AND p2.OrderId = p.OrderId) >= o.OrderValue
)
SELECT *
FROM paidInFullPayments
INNER JOIN OrderTable o ON paidInFullPayments.OrderId = o.OrderId
WHERE  paidInFullPayments.PaymentDate = (SELECT min(p3.PaymentDate) 
                                            FROM paidInFullPayments p3 
                                            WHERE p3.OrderId = o.OrderId)
```